# Jmeter does not expand variables when itself stressed

Tags: jmeter

My Jmeter test plan is setting a token variable using a Regular Expression Extractor (a Post-Processor element), but upon a while this variable is not expanded in its value and as consequent ${token} is sent to the REST API under actual test.

I added Constant Delay Timer elements in between each request a user (thread) sends and it seems to overcome the problem to a great extend but not entirely. I still get some Bad Request from the API side.

I provide a screen capture

[image]

And a second screen capture showing the full test plan (or a large portion of it)

[image]

Can someone please explain why this happening and somehow resolve it ?

Comment: Are you using multiple Thread Groups? In which Thread Group you are extracting ${token}? Paste screen shot of whole Test Plan for understanding

Comment: There may be issue with your regular expression extractor, please post the details where you are fetching the token and passing it to the next request.

Comment: I'm using one Thread Group @SAIR. I'm getting the token from the response headers (POST login sampler) and I think it is inevitable to use Regular Expression Extractor. I already edited and added another screen capture. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be the case your Regular Expression Extractor fails to find the value therefore it falls back to the default (undefined) value of `${token}`

My expectation is that under the load your application cannot properly respond, to wit response doesn't contain the token. You can double check it using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script/) combination.

You can temporarily [enable saving of response data](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config) by adding the next lines to *user.properties* file:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true
```

and next time you [run your test in command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) JMeter will keep response data for all samplers. You should be able to examine the responses and add a [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) to ensure that the token is present in the `POST LOGIN` sampler response data